# creating pollable message source

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to create a pollable message source and I have tried to do that by extending `MessageProducerSupport`, however I was able to see the message from receive method only once and was not successful in making it pollable. (The receive method is not getting called based on my polling schedule.)

My code snippet is as below:

```
@Component
public class MyAdapter extends MessageProducerSupport {

    @Override
    protected void doStart() {
        receive();
    }

    public void receive() {
        System.out.println("polled at : "+   new Date());
        sendMessage(MessageBuilder.withPayload("Hello WOrld! "+ new Date()).build());
    }
}
```

And my `applicationContext` is as below:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage" />
<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="pollerTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor"/>

<int:inbound-channel-adapter ref="myAdapter" channel="output">
    <int:poller task-executor="pollerTaskExecutor">
        <int:interval-trigger interval="3000" fixed-rate="true" time-unit="MILLISECONDS"/>
    </int:poller>
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I would like to know what am I missing to make this message source pollable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right: the *pollable message source* is based . erm... on `org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSource`.

So, to make it working you just should move your `MessageProducerSupport` code to the `AbstractMessageSource` implementation.

See more info in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/overview.html#programming-tips).

Comment: Hi, no luck extending `AbstractMessageSource`, any other thoughts?

Comment: Well, than something strange is around in your code. The Framework has a lot of `AbstractMessageSource` implementaitons and all they work well for the `SourcePollingChannelAdapter`. Share, please, some test-case to prove that it is otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! Working now!!